# Why select query returns more records but inserts less into file

Tags: shell, file, google-bigquery, bulkinsert

I have implemented bq in .sh script as below:

```
bq query --quiet -- format=csv --use legacy_sql = false \
"
Select table_id from \project_name.table_name\
Where table_id not like 'object_name'
" | sed '1d' > bq_table_list.txt
```

The problem is Select query is giving 40k results but the file `bq_table_list.txt` is holding only 100 records. Can anyone please tell why ?

```
Select table_id from project_name.table_name
Where table_id not like 'object_name' ---- 40k records
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: _is giving 40k_ .... (1) What is the meaning of "40k results"?  Approximately 40000 lines, or a result of size 40000 bytes? How do you know from this code, that your  `select` returns this number of records?

Comment: Also, I don't know about `bigquery`, but `legacy_sql = false` looks flakey.  Shouldn't it be `legacy_sql=false`?

Answer (score 0):

By default the BQ CLI only returns 100 rows.  use the `max_rows` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference) to increase this limit.